# Rails: Testing OAuth API by posting multiparted messages with file attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http, oauth-2.0, multipart

I have a Rails app with OAuth API. I'm using Doorkeeper gem for the OAuth 2 authentication. My API allows posting messages with image file attachments. I'd like to test it from Ruby console. Now, the problem is - how do I sign the post requests with the access token?

Doorkeeper wiki provides a tutorial on testing API with the OAuth2 gem itself. The problem there is that OAuth2 class doesn't provide ways of posting multiparted messages with the file attachments (as far as I got it).

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper/wiki/Testing-your-provider-with-OAuth2-gem

Then again there is multipart-post gem, which allows posting files as attachment to the Rails API. But I don't get how to sign such request with an access_token, and to pass the Doorkeeper authentication.

https://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post

So what is the proper way of posting multiparted messages to Rails API signed with the access_token?

Answer (score 2):

The oauth2 gem seems to not support multipart upload. Check this issue: https://github.com/intridea/oauth2/issues/81

An workaround would include the `access_token` in your parameters, either as a query string or  as a header. Following the example in README:

```
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/upload')
File.open("./image.jpg") do |jpg|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path,
    "file" => UploadIO.new(jpg, "image/jpeg", "image.jpg")

  # here you include the token in headers
  req['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{THE_ACCESS_TOKEN}"
  res = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port) do |http|
    http.request(req)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You also have to explicitly set the ssl on  if you have this error:

```
EOFError in YourController#youraction 
end of file reached
```

Exemple

```
require 'net/http/post/multipart'

url = URI.parse('http://www.example.com/upload')
File.open("./image.jpg") do |jpg|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new url.path, 
    "file" => UploadIO.new(jpg, "image/jpeg", "image.jpg")

  # here you include the token in headers
  req['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{THE_ACCESS_TOKEN}"

  http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)

  #mention the use of ssl
  http.use_ssl = true

  res = http.request(req)
end
```